# Magento: Disable Layout Page Templates like 3-columns.phtml and so on

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to create entire website based on 2 columns only. So I want to remove all one column and 3 column layouts.

I want to remove these options even from the administration area.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite (whether by using app/code/local or by using a module) Mage_Page_Model_Source_Layout::getOptions() like this:

```
/**
 * Retrieve page layout options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getOptions()
{

    // Array of layout codes that are allowed
    $allowedLayoutCodes = array('empty', 'two_columns_left', 'two_columns_right');

    if ($this->_options === null) {
        $this->_options = array();
        foreach (Mage::getSingleton('page/config')->getPageLayouts() as $layout) {

            // If layoutCode in foreach loop is allowed
            if(in_array($layout->getCode(), $allowedLayoutCodes)) {
                $this->_options[$layout->getCode()] = $layout->getLabel();
                if ($layout->getIsDefault()) {
                    $this->_defaultValue = $layout->getCode();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return $this->_options;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Remove Layout option from administrative area, you have to edit core file. For this pls comment required layouts in app\code\core\Mage\Page\etc\config.xml.

Please Make sure that you have removed all removed layout references from your frontend theme.

Comment: -1 for advising to edit Core files. Core files must NEVER be edited. Please see my answer.